# Migrate [symfony] tag before it becomes confusing

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retag symfony-2.0 to symfony2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137230/retag-symfony-2-0-to-symfony2)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony

Symfony1.4 and Symfony2 are [entirely different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858095/upgrading-from-symfony1-to-symfony2) that share a namesake and made by the same people.

Right now we have [Symfony-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony+symfony-1.4) (and also 1.2)

We also have [Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony+symfony-2.0) tags.

Given that this framework is fairly new, can we update all posts tagged with [Symfony] *before* July 2011 (Symfony2 released) to something that better represents these questions are about the old framework, not the new one with a similar name, ban the "Symfony" tag and enforce use of either Symfony1 or Symfony2 to prevent confusion in the future regarding which one the question is about?

I just want to prevent a future where we have a lot of questions tagged "AppleOrange" rather than "apple" or "orange".