# Retag symfony-2.0 to symfony2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-2.0/info

[symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) is semantically wrong as it refers to actual application minor version (2.**0**), rather than major (symfony2 vs symfony1), meaning that, semantically, questions related to 2.**1** version (which is officially in beta as of today) will be tagged wrongly.
And we already have a tag synonym that suits better - symfony2, which we should use.

So in short my proposal is to switch tag priority between symfony-2.0 and symfony2 - make symfony2 the main tag and symfony-2.0 a synonym of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've done:

- [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) has been renamed to [symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1)
- [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) has been renamed to [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2).
- [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) is now a *synonym* for [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2), based on the discussion below.

Also based on that discussion, [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) has been re-created specifically for the .0 minor version.

Comment: @j0k, elnur it would be interesting to discuss next steps. Can we meet in a chat room? Maybe today at 12:00 CET? Shog9, If you want to attend also, please do!

Comment: I can only notify one user per comment, so this is for @elnur also

Comment: I will (hopefully) be sound asleep by then. But please do report back on your recommendations.

Comment: After talking about this, we still need a couple of things: We need a new "symfony-2.0" tag. People will use it when they have a problem which is specific to this version of Symfony2. And we don´t need that "Symfony" is a synonym of "Symfony1". We prefer if people use "Symfony1" or "Symfony2" as they are very different beasts. We´d be grateful if you could implement this.

Comment: Okay, so wait, should the synonym exist or not?  I just found myself accidentally creating the tag during an edit, forgetting that this had been done.  I expected the versionless tag to still be a synonym as is described here...

Comment: I think we need to let the [tag:symfony] to be a synonym of [tag:symfony1]. For me, a question tagged only with [tag:symfony2] we be for 2.0 version. Then we need [tag:symfony-2.0] to be a synonym of [tag:symfony2]. But we can discuss this on the chat.

Comment: I suggest you raise a new meta discussion regarding the synonyms.

Comment: @j0k when can we meet on the chat to talk about this?

Comment: @elnur when can we meet on the chat to talk about this?

Comment: Tomorrow afternoon? Like 3pm gmt+2

Comment: Can we do it in the morning? Like 12pm gmt+2? In the afternoon I have things to do

Comment: @CarlosGranados finally I won't be available tomorrow. Can we need on Monday during business hour?

Comment: Fine, on monday

Comment: Whoa, I missed this answer. Sorry.

Comment: @Shog9, we held a discussion this morning (see transcript: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/529/2012/9/24) and we finally agreed on this: we needed a new "symfony-2.0" tag but this was already created by elnur a couple of days ago. We debated if we could ask for the "symfony" synonym to be deleted, but then people would continue adding it as a tag and recreating it, so this would be an unending battle. So finally we agreed that "symfony" should be a synonym of "symfony2". Can you please implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Carlos: this has been done.

Answer (score 8):

I totally agree with this. I suggest making the [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) tag the main one and [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0), [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1) and others just the version tags to specify a version when it is important.

Basically, we just need to untie [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) from [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) and make it standalone. We'll retag the needed questions after that.

P.S. I'm the [top answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-2.0/topusers) of the [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) tag, so please take this into account.

---

It's getting very messy with [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) and [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1) questions. Somebody, please take action now.

Comment: It should be interesting to discuss before taking decision on your own (as you actually do).

Comment: Sure, I'm in the chat room.

Comment: I agree with your proposal

Comment: I've updated the answer with the resolution me, j0k and CarlosGranados came to in [our discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/16862).

Comment: step one (dissociate [tag:symfony] from [tag:symfony-2.0]: done. Next step ask to rename [tag:symfony] to [tag:symfony1] and [tag:symfony-2.0] to [tag:symfony2]

Comment: @j0k, great job!

Comment: It will also be neccessary to edit the tag wiki for those tags

Comment: @CarlosGranados tag wiki edit done (for [tag:symfony1], [tag:symfony2], [tag:symfony-1.4] & [tag:symfony-2.1])

Comment: I added a few minor edits, please see if they are OK

Comment: @CarlosGranados looks good to me. I think we are done with this mess :) Thanks guys !

Comment: I think there is still a couple of things to do: a) We need a tag for symfony-2.0, so that people who have questions about that specific version can tag them b)I think that there is no need for a "symfony" synonim for "symfony1". People should just use "Symfony1" or "Symfony2". Do you agree?

Comment: @CarlosGranados, yea, I agree that we need the [symfony-2.0] tag and we don't need the [symfony] tag.

Comment: Great job, guys.

Comment: I created a chat room to discuss this: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/529/symfony-tags. I am available now, please join when available

Answer (score 1):

This is not the first time people try to change the way [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) (and related) works.

- [Tag chaos: [symfony] and version numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138683/tag-chaos-symfony-and-version-numbers)
- [Migrate [symfony] tag before it becomes confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123300/migrate-symfony-tag-before-it-becomes-confusing)

I think the best solution is to discuss (why not in [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16862/symfony)) about what we can do with all tags related to symfony and it minor/major version and, [as suggested in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138683/tag-chaos-symfony-and-version-numbers#comment-390291), do the change by our self. Yep it means edit all questions tagged with symfony..

What do you think?

Comment: I created a chat room to discuss this: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/529/symfony-tags. I am available now, please join when available