# Tag chaos: [symfony] and version numbers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retag symfony-2.0 to symfony2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137230/retag-symfony-2-0-to-symfony2)

Right now there is a bit of a chaos if one has a look at the Symfony tags.

[symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony)

There is the tag [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony), which is most used right now (4198 questions). It holds no information about the major version, which is very bad, as version 1 and 2 are essentially different frameworks with almost nothing in common (well, they both use yaml files and swiftmailer, but thats about it). The description on the tag is clearly written with Symfony 1 in mind. People are using it for both versions, which makes this tag useless when filtering for specific information.

[symfony-1.2](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.2) / [symfony-1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4)

The tags symfony-1.2 (4 questions) and symfony1.4 (1326) all refer to the same major version. Their might be some specifics which changed, but overall it's the code base. Merging this tags into a [symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1) tag would be benefitial for everyone looking for information on Symfony 1.

[symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) / [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1)

Same situation: Their might be some specifics which will change between 2.0 and 2.1 (which is beta right now), but overall most questions asked with Symfony 2.0 in mind (3891) are valid for 2.1 (10 questions so far).

**How to solve this dilemma?**

From my point of view, there are some ways to solve this:

- "Deprecating" the [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony), adding a [symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1) and having all minor version tags be a synonym for the major version tag.
- Using the [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) for version 1 and the [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) tag for version 2, again making minor versions synonyms.

At least I would vote to somehow prevent people from using the generic [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony). Working with symfony everyday, it's annoying to have no tag to rely on. symfony is way to generic and one ends up with half the questions about the "wrong" framework.

Maybe more experienced people can contribute their knowledge on how such situations where solved in the past. I think solving this tag problem would make stackoverflow to a more valuable source of answers for symfony developers.

Comment: Chaos Symfony should be a new Castlevania game

Comment: I know nothing about Symfony. If the situation is as you describe, then deprecating [tag:symfony] and manually going through the 4k questions to retag them to [tag:symfony1] or [tag:symfony2] is the right way. Deprecating the tag is conveyed by directing people to other tags in the tag wiki. Then you need a lot of editors (a posse) who can tell the difference between Symfony 1 and Symfony 2.

Comment: Currently, I'm removing the [tag:symfony] tag from Symfony2 questions. I think it'll take several days to several weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) big picture, from my perspective *(I don't use or know Symfony)*:

> [image]

There's a lot of questions based on the generic [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony), so it is safe to assume that is the common denominator for this tag and should not be changed.

As per the [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) versions, users appear to be accustomed to the following scheme:

```
name-version
```

Resulting on the search for tags like: [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1) [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) [symfony-1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4) [symfony-1.2](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.2)

**What I can conclude from this is that:**

- the generic [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) should be preserved and have a solid wiki, since this tag is and continue to be used to identify this framework.
- the sub-consequent tags like [symfony-x.x](/questions/tagged/symfony-x.x) should be kept since users are making use of them to target a specific version they are using and/or having problem with!
- the remaining variants regarding the framework version should be merged with the above two:

  **e.g.,**

  [symfony1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony1.4) would be merged thus becomming [symfony-1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4)

---

I know this not exactly what you have suggested as a solution, but from my ignorant point of view, users that use [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) speak for themselves as seem on the number of questions using the [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) and [symfony-1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4).

Comment: I would agree if symfony2 would be the next version, like if you compare PHP4 and 5. Things have changed, but most of the stuff is the same. You can use classes now and so on, but many questions are generic php questions, not specific to one version. symfony on the other hand is a complete new implementation with fundamental different concepts. Not a single file is in the same place, not a single class reused (except for third party stuff like swiftmailer). A question regarding symfony1 will never help anyone using symfony2.

Comment: We are talking about that [on the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16862/symfony) if you would like to join us.