# Change a tag synonym? [symfony2] = [symfony-2.0], should now be [symfony-2.1]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retag symfony-2.0 to symfony2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137230/retag-symfony-2-0-to-symfony2)

Right now, [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) is a synonym of [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0). But the version 2.1 has been recently released and is now the "official" master version. How do I propose a change so that [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) becomes a synonym of [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1)?

I tried proposing [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) as a synonym of [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1) but it won´t let me, I guess because it already exists.

Comment: [tag:symfony2] is a synonym of [tag:symfony-2.0], which means no questions currently have the [tag:symfony2] tag. How would you handle that?

Comment: If you follow your own link, you will see that stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2 redirects to stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0. What needs to be done is that it redirects to stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually moderators wait to see the community's reaction to such propositions. Two upvotes (as I write) doesn't show significant community support by Meta.SO standards.

Your proposition seems weird to me, but I don't know anything about Symfony. Is there really a need for separate tags for Symfony 2.1 and Symfony 2.0? And for Symfony 2 as distinct from Symfony 1? Version-specific tags should only be used for questions that only apply to this version. If a question applies to both Symfony 1 and Symfony 2, it should be tagged [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) only. Unless Symfony completely breaks compatibility with every version, [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) should probably be merged into [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) and removed as a tag name. If there really needs to be a separate tag for 2.0 and 2.1, they should not be synonyms.

Comment: Symfony 1 and 2 are two completely different beasts and they should not be mixed. The situation for Symfony 2 is as follows: for 1 year version 2.0 has been the "official" version. Now the 2.1 version has been released and is the official version. There are many BC changes and many times advice which is good for 2.1 is not good for 2.0 and viceversa. Right now all new users are installing version 2.1 and little by little a lot of 2.0 users will move to 2.1. At some point in time (maybe not yet) it will make sense that "symfony2" refers to  "symfony-2.1", not "symfony-2.0"

Comment: I can suggest to add a new synonym but I have not found a way to suggest a change to the "meaning" of one synonym. What I want to know if this can be done and how. I don´t really want to suggest this change just yet but I want to know how to suggest it when it feels "right"

Comment: @CarlosGranados Users can suggest and vote on new synonyms. Only moderators can do more complex things. You reach a moderator by asking on meta and waiting for the community to support (or refute) you. As there's a lot of traffic on Meta.SO, moderators might miss threads sometimes; you can try to catch one in chat. If you don't know where to look, leave a message in [the Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly); it's not very active, but if you post there, someone will usually relay to the right person.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It seems I can´t award you a bounty just yet. I´ll wait the neccessary time and if no other better answer arrives, then it´s yours!

Comment: Maybe you can edit your answer to reflect your last comment, which I think is the "real" answer

Comment: @CarlosGranados The [meta-tag:synonym-request] tag wiki already links to the [tag synonym FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) which has a section on deleting tag synonyms, that's where the information should go. Hmm, I've revamped that FAQ a bit.

Comment: I'd suggest that to match version naming defacto standards we have in place, it should be named `symfony-2`.  Maybe even `symfony-2.x`.